# How can I extract url from json data with escaped "\" in java

Tags: java, json, regex

I need to extract url from json filed. (replace it with "" and do not break the json format), so that there's no url in json.

the url looks in this way

```
"source":"\u003ca href=\"http:\/\/twitter.com\/download\/iphone\",
"profile_image_url_https":"https:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/profile_images\/3475536942\/2b0ccd9e42754adf7e22947037dd8c34_normal.jpeg","profile_banner_url":"https:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/profile_banners\/488849893\/1364691799",
```

...

I noticed that there's "\" in the url to escape the string, I don't know how to deal with it while writing the regex.

Comment: use a json parser no regex

Comment: I need to deal with lot's of data and this is just a sample of it. just use parser may not be a good idea? I don't know at which filed the url located.

Comment: @Jens is right, if you use a parser like Jackson you can configure it to parse escaped JSON. You have lots data, this is one reason to use a parser like Jackson :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply use a lightweight JSON parser such as [this reference implementation in Java](https://github.com/stleary/JSON-java)

To overwrite, say, the `source` property to "blah", it is possible to do things as simple as

```
String newJsonString = new JSONObject(originalJsonString).putString("source","blah").toString();
```